# The function collects the array and returns it. After ciout memory is still occupied by this array, right?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, cout

I have the following function:

```
void setFore(const short arg) {
         char ansicode[12] = "\e[38;5;";
         char code[4];
         snprintf(code, 4, "%d", arg);
         strcat(ansicode, code);
         strcat(ansicode, "m");
         std::cout << ansicode; }
```

Using it looks like

```
std::cout << "Some text";
setFore(50);
std::cout << "Some text\n";
```

After execution, array ansicode is deleted automatically.
I want to make the function like this:

```
char* setFore(const short arg) {
         char ansicode[12] = "\e[38;5;";
         char code[4];
         snprintf(code, 4, "%d", arg);
         strcat(ansicode, code);
         strcat(ansicode, "m");
         return &ansicode; }
```

And use it as `std::cout << "Some text" << setFore(50) << "Some text\n";`.
But one question remains, will the memory occupied by the ansicode array continue to occupy the memory? Since the array is not created with new, it will not be possible to release it even after assigning a pointer. What should I do?

Comment: Maybe you want to write C++ code instead of C code, and use `std::string` and its methods, to create its contents, instead of a `char` array and C library functions like `strcat`? And returning `std::string` from a function becomes a big, fat, nothing-burger.

Comment: Terminology: "array ansicode is **destroyed** automatically". You only `delete` something you created with `new`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for the advice! But I prefer char arrays ...

Comment: Can you explain why, exactly, you "prefer char arrays"? It's much easier to use `std::string` for this, in C++. This is what `std::string`s are for.

Comment: FYI, `'\e'` is not a [standard escape sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).  I recommend `'\x1b'` instead.  See also the [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I know that arrays run faster. This plays a role in writing something for the Arduino. Maybe our opinions are different, but please understand, I understand that you have a lot more experience than I do, I like words in arrays of chars, good old C ...

Comment: On today's multi-ghz CPUs, any speed difference is mostly academic, especially with copy elision. if you prefer to use arrays you'll need to create the arrays in the caller, and pass it in as a parameter to this function.

Comment: If `std::string` bothers you so much, you can use `std::array` of characters. Same "good old" properties, but with value semantics.

Comment: *"I like words in arrays of chars, good old C"* -- then why use C++ at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But one question remains, will the memory occupied by the ansicode array continue to occupy the memory?

C-style arrays have automatic lifetime, they will get destroyed after the local scope ends, so it is undefined behavior to try to do anything with them after the function has returned, you should consider using a container like `std::string`:

```cpp
std::string setFore(const short arg) {
     return "\033[38;5;" + std::to_string(arg) + "m";
}
```

Comment: Do you think that doing this, and having to use `delete[]`, is easier than simply using `std::string` in the first place, and letting the C++ library automatically take care of memory management for you?

Comment: And, if using the second version,  `std::cout << "Some text" << setFore(50) << "Some text\n";`, as mentioned in the question, won't work because there is no way to delete the array that `setFore(50)` creates.

Answer (score 3):

Returning a local array won't work since it'll be destroyed at the end of the function scope. I suggest using `std::string` and `std::ostringstream` instead:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string setFore(short arg) {
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << "\x1b[38;5;" << arg << 'm';
    return os.str(); 
}
```

If you *do* need a `char*` for some reason later, you can use the returned string's `data()` or `c_str()` member functions.

As Thomas Matthews noted in the comments, `\e` is not a standard escape sequence so I replaced it with the hex value `1b` (`27` dec).